# React onClick event does not fire setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build an image gallery in React.js, everything went smoothly until now.
In gallery I am creating Thumbnail objects - on click this will fire "mini gallery" with all pictures from particular project and description for project. However to get back to main gallery I am creating "CLOSE" button within "mini gallery" with an attached handler.
Thumbnail click works, however Close Button does not. Please see code attached below.
I will be very grateful for any help!
This is Main Gallery:

```js
import React from 'react';

import Thumbnail from '../components/Thumbnail';

export default class Drawings extends React.Component {
 render () {
  const linkPrefix = "./life/";
  const imageS = ".800.jpg";
  const imageL = ".jpg";
  const lifePics = [
   {
    name: "One",
    filename: [
     "lifedrawing1",
    ],
    descr: "one",
   },
   {
    name: "Two",
    filename: [
     "lifedrawing2",
     "lifedrawing2ed",
     "lifedrawing2ed2",
    ],
    descr: "two",
   },
   {
    name: "Three",
    filename: [
     "lifedrawing3",
    ],
    descr: "three",
   },
  ]
  return (
   <div id="Drawings" className="container row around wrap">
    {lifePics.map(
     (picture, i) =>
      <Thumbnail
       key={i}
       linkPrefix={linkPrefix}
       filename={picture.filename}
       imageS={imageS}
       imageL={imageL}
      />
    )}
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

This is each Thumbnail:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Thumbnail extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewerDisplay: "hidden",
    };
 }

 thumbnailClick(event) {
  this.setState({
   viewerDisplay: "visible",
  });
 }

 closeViewer(event) {
  this.setState({
   viewerDisplay: "hidden",
  });
 }

 render () {
  const thumbnailStyle = {
   width: '45%',
   height: '300px',
   backgroundImage: 'url('+this.props.linkPrefix + this.props.filename[0]+this.props.imageS+')',
   backgroundSize: 'cover',
   marginBottom: '10px',
   cursor: 'pointer',
  };
  var viewerStyle = {
   position: "absolute",
   top: "300px",
   right: "50px",
   bottom: "10px",
   left: "50px",
   visibility: this.state.viewerDisplay,
   background: "black",
   cursor: "auto",
  };
  const viewerColStyle = {
   width: "50%",
   height: "100%",
  }

  return (
   <div
    className="thumbnail container col between"
    style={thumbnailStyle}
    onClick={this.thumbnailClick.bind(this)}
   >
    <div
     id="Viewer"
     className="viewer container row between"
     style={viewerStyle}
    >
     <div
      id="PicList"
      className="container col around"
      style={viewerColStyle}
     >
      Thumbnails
      {//map function for thumbnails of particular gallery
      }
     </div>
     <div
      id="ProjectDescr"
      className="container col around"
      style={viewerColStyle}
     >
      Project Descr
     </div>
     <button
      onClick={this.closeViewer.bind(this)}
     >CLOSE</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: did you add a `console.log` in closeViewer function ? just to make sure it goes inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `event.stopPropagation()` to the `closeViewer` function to prevent propagation of the click event to **Thumbnail** div element

```
closeViewer(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({
        viewerDisplay: "hidden",
    });
}
```

Here is an example without stopPropagation

```html
<body>
   <div onclick="clickDiv()">
      <button onclick="clickButton()">Test</button>
   </div>
 
   <script>
      function clickButton() {
        alert('clickButton');
      }
   
      function clickDiv() {
         alert('clickDiv');
      }
   </script>
</body>
```

Here is an example with stopPropagation

```html
<body>
   <div onclick="clickDiv()">
      <button onclick="clickButton(event)">Test</button>
   </div>
 
   <script>
      function clickButton(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();
         alert('clickButton');
      }
   
      function clickDiv() {
      alert('clickDiv');
      }
    </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you for your help. All works like it should with tweak you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your click handler in the constructor or make it an arrow function in order to pass context:

```
thumbnailClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        viewerDisplay: "visible",
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried different approaches from [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56). The thing is if I add colsole.log() statement to my handler it works, it just does not change state of my component - Thumbnail.

Comment: @MaciekJarmula That's weird, try adding a different key for <Thumbnail /> maybe a combination between filename and index key={`${i}_${picture.filename}`}